# How to use Foreach loop using the ext/dom to output XML

Tags: javascript, php, xml, dom, foreach

On a php script, how does one do a foreach loop using a string and/or the ext/dom to output XML data that gets values from a msql database? 
EDITED: Latest work

```
<?php
#Programmer: Moses Byanyuma

require('./.env');


// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME. ';charset=utf8',  DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "An Error occured, could not connect!";
}

$statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM markers');

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$markers = $xml->createElement('markers');
$markers = $xml->appendChild($markers);

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

     $marker = $xml->createElement('marker');
     $markers->appendChild($marker);

     $marker->setAttribute('name', $row['name']);
    $marker->setAttribute('lat', $row['lat']);
    $marker->setAttribute('lng', $row['lng']);
    $marker->setAttribute('address', $row['address']);
    $marker->setAttribute('type', $row['type']);

}


echo "<xmp>".$xml->saveXML()."</xmp>";

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? I posted a link to an DOM example in your previous question.

Comment: @ThW just edited this post, I've made a little progress but i'm struggling to get the values from the database into the xml, please see my foreach loop

Comment: @ThW for example i tried: $name = $xml->createAttribute('name', $row['name']); but on the browser i get an error saying createAttribute only expects one parameter and it has to be only a string.
Then i tried replacing createAttribute with getAttribute but that totally didn't work, got an undefined function error, idk what to do : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMDocument::createAttribute()` has no second argument. I suggest using `DOMElement::setAttribute()`. But you can create the attribute as a node if you like:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$foo = $document->appendChild(
  $document->createElement('foo')
);

// just set the attribute
$foo ->setAttribute('one', '1');

// create and configure the attribute node
$attribute = $document->createAttribute('two');
$attribute->value = '2';
// set it on the element
$foo->setAttributeNode($attribute);

// create and apppend and attribute
$attribute = $foo->appendChild(
  $document->createAttribute('three')
);
// the value is actually a text node
$attribute->appendChild(
  $document->createTextNode('3')
);

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I just edited this post. I made progress but i have one major problem:

Comment: It's not a complete xml in the sense that it looks like plain text. On my index.html file the data points are not showing on the map because the values are not being pulled from the .php file, i dont know why

Comment: i was just trying to edit my own post and accidentally edited yours, my bad. but yeah thats the output that shows on my browser, except it's just plain black text so i don't think its an actual xml output thats why the coordinates are not showing on the map, help please :/

Comment: Check the source view of the browser, by default the response is sent out as HTML, the browser will render it and ignore non HTML tags. The result is that only the text nodes are visible. You can use `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');` to sent an XML content type. Search SO for answers on this topic.

Comment: It worked :) thank you so much. I've moved on to a new project, I'm learning how to use highchartsJS and will start a project on it probably by tomorrow or day after!